# Не вызывается метод getRoles() через CustomUserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Пишу серверное приложение при помощи Hibernate и Spring, пользуюсь  видео образцом. Автор в определённый момент   прописывает вот такой метод:

```
`    public static User build(User user) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name())).collect(Collectors.toList());
return new User(
            user.getId(),
            user.getUsername(),
            user.getEmail(),
            user.getPassword(),
            authorities);
}`
```

[image: Общая картина]

По какой причине у меня не видит getRoles? Пишет что можно его создать в классе User и всё. У автора всё легко и просто. Подскажите, пожалуйста.
[image: Моё изображение]

```
    package com.example.demo.entity;

import com.example.demo.entity.enums.ERole;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.*;

@Entity
@Data
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;
@Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
private String username;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String lastname;
@Column(unique = true)
private String email;
@Column(columnDefinition = "text")
private String bio;
@Column(length = 3000)
private String password;

@ElementCollection(targetClass = ERole.class)
@CollectionTable(name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
private Set<ERole> roles = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")
@Column(updatable = false)
private LocalDateTime createdDate;

@Transient
private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

public User() {
}

public User(Long id,
            String username,
            String email,
            String password,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.authorities = authorities;
}

@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    this.createdDate = LocalDateTime.now();
}

/**
 * SECURITY
 */



@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Скорее всего вам надо унаследовать User от UserDetails

Comment: UserDetails - интерфейс. Это условие у меня выполнено, как и у автора. 
"public class User implements UserDetails"

Comment: Вы ещё, может быть, с автором видео используете разные версии спринга. Последние пару лет там многое поменялось и большая часть инфы в сети - устаревшая и неактуальная, к сожалению.

Comment: а Вы можете подсказать как мне реализовать тоже самое, что имел ввиду автор или как правильно это убрать, чтобы не повлияло на функционал приложения?

Comment: Сложно сказать, надо по ситуации смотреть. Покажите, для начала, класс User - возможно там есть то что вам нужно, просто называется по другому.

Comment: добавил класс User в вопрос

Comment: Собственно как вам в ответе и написали - создайте метод получения ролей. Не очень понятно что вас смущает

Answer (score 1):

Убедитесь что у вас метод getRoles() создан и имеет индефикатор доступа public

Comment: Он не создан, когда автор его вызывает в eclipse подсвечивается, что он из Set. Там в классе User написан private Set<ERole> roles = new HashSet<>();